# Does Eclipse not infer generics for anonymous classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

The following piece of java code is highlighted red in Eclipse *but it compiles fine*.
The IDE error is:

> Type mismatch, cannot convert from type `Optional<Runnable>` from
>   `Optional<new Runnable>`

The compiler should be fine with this from inferred generics but my IDE fails. Is there an incorrect setting somewhere in Eclipse?

```
Optional<Runnable> o;

o = Optional.of(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

  }
});
```

Comment: Please comment on what makes this downvote-worthy?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't have a problem

Comment: And also the fact that your Question's formatting was mangled to the point of meaninglessness until someone fixed it for you.

Comment: I would imagine that this is caused because `new Runnable() { .. }` returns a *sub-type* of Runnable. `Runnable r = new Runnable ..; o = Optional.of(r)` should not have a problem. Perhaps differences in compiler language version?

Comment: Thanks for fixing it Stephen, never noticed that my <'s were removed. But I'd hardly call that "mangled to point of meaninglessness"

Comment: So what does *"Type mismatch, cannot convert from type Optional from Optional"* mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

This should be:

```
Optional <Runnable> o;

o = Optional.<Runnable>of (new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        /* your code here */
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldnt the generics be infer-able?

Comment: @Kurru - that depends on your selected Java language level.

Comment: @StephenC see below, it fails for both 1.6, 1.7. Don't have 1.5 handy.

Comment: @Kurru the generic `T` **is** inferred, but in the original code it is inferred to the (anonymous) subtype of `Runnable`.  It would be the same case if you created an explicitly named subtype of `Runnable`, like `class MyRunnable implements Runnable { ... }; Optional<Runnable> o = Optional.of(new MyRunnable())`.  As another example, this situation is analogous to something like `List<Number> list = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1))`.  So this is actually the correct behavior for Java, regardless of version.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 7 enabled under Eclipse, two lines are necessary to handle your syntax:

```
Runnable t = new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {/**/}};
Optional< Runnable > o = Optional.of( t );
```

Answer (score 0):

As others point out two lines or Optional.<Optional>of() is necessary.

javac (jdk 1.7) fails:

```
error: incompatible types
  o = Optional.of(new Runnable() {
                 ^
  required: Optional<Runnable>
  found:    Optional<<anonymous Runnable>>
1 error
```

javac (jdk 1.6) also fails:

```
incompatible types
found   : Optional<<anonymous java.lang.Runnable>>
required: Optional<java.lang.Runnable>
  o = Optional.of(new Runnable() {
                 ^
1 error
```

So it seems like this is the defined Java behaviour, don't know why though.